# Update/refresh fragment on button click

Tags: android, android-fragments

I created a very simple test app which consists of:

- 2 fragments
- 2 buttons (in fragment 1)
- 1 textview (in fragment 2)
- SharedPreferences for both fragments
- a ViewPager which lets you swipe from fragment 1 to 2 and vice versa

My aim is that every time I click on a specific button in fragment 1,
the textview of fragment 2 gets updated.

This works, however, I always have to rotate the display first, so that the fragment/view gets refreshed.

I found some threads here, but it seems there are many different ways.

From what I understood, one way would be to detach fragment 2, update it, and attach it again.

The question is:

Do I have to modify also the code of fragment 2, or is it enough to modify the method
savePreferences in fragment 1?

MainActivity:

```
        import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    {
        ViewPager vp; // Variable for Viewpager
        private static final String TAG = "MainActivity"; // Not sure if needed

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            ViewPager vp = findViewById(R.id.vp); // Link variable to ID
            SetUpViewPager(vp); // Run method
        }
        public void SetUpViewPager(ViewPager viewpage)
        {
            MyViewPagerAdapter Adapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            Adapter.AddPageFragment(new Fragment1(), "Fragment1"); // Load page 1 inside of ViewPager
            Adapter.AddPageFragment(new Fragment2(), "Fragment2"); // Load page 1 inside of ViewPager
            viewpage.setAdapter(Adapter);
        }
        public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
        {
            private List<Fragment> MyFragment = new ArrayList<>();
            private List<String> MyPageTitle = new ArrayList<>();

            public MyViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager)
            {
                super(manager);
            }
            public void AddPageFragment(Fragment Frag, String Title)
            {
                MyFragment.add(Frag);
                MyPageTitle.add(Title);
            }
            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int i)
            {
                return MyFragment.get(i);
            }
            @Nullable
            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
            {
                return MyPageTitle.get(position);
            }
            @Override
            public int getCount()
            {
                return 2; // 2 pages total
            }
        }
    }
```

Fragment1:

```
        import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    public class Fragment1 extends Fragment
    {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View fragmentOne = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false); // Link view and layout
            Button button1 = fragmentOne.findViewById(R.id.button_1); // Link variable to ID
            Button button2 = fragmentOne.findViewById(R.id.button_2); // Link variable to ID
            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    savePreferences("1");
                }
            });
            button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    savePreferences("2");
                }
            });
            return fragmentOne;
        }
        public void savePreferences(String text)
        {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // Create new SharedPreferences instance
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit(); // Create variable for SharedPreferences
            editor.putString("text", text); // Write text coming from button inside of editor
            editor.apply(); // Apply and close SharedPreferences instance
            Log.wtf("Text is: ", text); // Check if text is correct - yes, it's correct
        }
    }
```

Fragment2:

```
        import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    public class Fragment2 extends Fragment
    {
        String text; // Text which gets shown inside of TextView
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View fragmentTwo = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false); // Link view and layout
            loadSharedPreferences(); // Load SharedPreferences
            TextView textViewValue = fragmentTwo.findViewById(R.id.text_view); // Link variable to ID
            textViewValue.setText(text); // Show loaded value
            return fragmentTwo;
        }
        public void loadSharedPreferences()
        {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // Load SharedPreferences
            text = prefs.getString("text", "0"); // Retrieve text from Shared Preferences
        }
    }
```

**Edit - 20.09.18**
Third version of Fragment2:

```
        import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Fragment2 extends Fragment
    {
        String text;
        private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener preferenceChangeListener;
        private static final String STATE_TEXT = "state_text";
        SharedPreferences prefs;

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View fragmentTwo = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false); // Link view and layout
            final TextView textViewValue = fragmentTwo.findViewById(R.id.text_view); // Link variable to ID
            prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            preferenceChangeListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
                {
                    switch (key)
                    {
                        case "text":
                            String text = sharedPreferences.getString("text", "0");
                            textViewValue.setText(text);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            };
            prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceChangeListener);
            return fragmentTwo;
        };
        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
        {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putString(STATE_TEXT, text);
        }
        @Override
        public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
            text = savedInstanceState.getString(STATE_TEXT);
        }
        @Override
        public void onDestroy()
        {
            super.onDestroy();
            if (preferenceChangeListener != null)
            {
                prefs.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceChangeListener);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Edit - 24.09.18**

Fragment1:

```
        import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    public class Fragment1 extends Fragment
    {
        String text;
        int bColor;
        SharedPreferences prefs;
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View fragmentOne = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false); // Link view and layout
            Button button1 = fragmentOne.findViewById(R.id.button_1); // Link variable to ID
            Button button2 = fragmentOne.findViewById(R.id.button_2); // Link variable to ID
            Button buttonColorRed = fragmentOne.findViewById(R.id.button_color_red); // Link variable to ID
            Button buttonColorBlue = fragmentOne.findViewById(R.id.button_color_blue); // Link variable to ID
            prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            bColor = prefs.getInt("bcolor", 0);
            text = prefs.getString("text", "0");
            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    text = "1";
                    savePreferences();
                }
            });
            button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    text = "2";
                    savePreferences();
                }
            });
            buttonColorRed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    bColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.red);
                    savePreferences();
                }
            });
            buttonColorBlue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    bColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.blue);
                    savePreferences();
                }
            });
            return fragmentOne;
        }
        public void savePreferences()
        {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // Create new SharedPreferences instance
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit(); // Create variable for SharedPreferences
            editor.putString("text", text); // Write text coming from button inside of editor
            editor.putInt("bcolor", bColor); // Write background color coming from button inside of editor
            editor.apply(); // Apply and close SharedPreferences instance
            Log.wtf("Text is: ", text); // Check if text is correct - yes, it's correct
        }
    }
```

Fragment2:

```
        import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Fragment2 extends Fragment
    {
        String text;
        int bColor;
        private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener preferenceChangeListener;
        SharedPreferences prefs;
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View fragmentTwo = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false); // Link view and layout
            final TextView textViewValue = fragmentTwo.findViewById(R.id.text_view); // Link variable to ID
            final ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = fragmentTwo.findViewById(R.id.constraint_layout);
            prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            text = prefs.getString("text", "0");
            textViewValue.setText(text);
            bColor = prefs.getInt("bcolor", 0);
            constraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(bColor);
            preferenceChangeListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
                {
                    switch (key)
                    {
                        case "text":
                            text = sharedPreferences.getString("text", "0");
                            textViewValue.setText(text);
                        case "bcolor":
                            bColor = sharedPreferences.getInt("bcolor", getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                            constraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(bColor);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            };
            prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceChangeListener);
            return fragmentTwo;
        };
        @Override
        public void onDestroy()
        {
            super.onDestroy();
            if (preferenceChangeListener != null)
            {
                prefs.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceChangeListener);
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To unregister your listener make it a global variable. Try below:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

    String text;
    private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener preferenceChangeListener;
    SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View fragmentTwo = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false); // Link view and layout

        final TextView textViewValue = fragmentTwo.findViewById(R.id.text_view); // Link variable to ID

        prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        preferenceChangeListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
                switch (key)
                {
                    case "text":
                        String text = sharedPreferences.getString("text", "0");
                        textViewValue.setText(text);
                    break;
                }
            }
        };

        prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceChangeListener);
        return fragmentTwo;
    };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (preferenceChangeListener != null){
            prefs.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceChangeListener);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Please note that Listener will be unregistered when `Fragment2` is destroyed. This usually happens when there are three fragments in tablayout and you go to 3rd tab, the first tab fragment will be destroyed unless you have increased offscreenpages in your `ViewPager`.

To counter this problem set text to your text view from `SharedPreference` in `onCreateView` of `Fragment2`, so it will update when it is reloaded in ViewPager. You won't notice problems right now, but if you add another tab to you ViewPager there might be problem and this is solution to that.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your super fast answer. Can you please take a look at the new code? (I added it in the first post). Before I unregister the listener, I must be sure that it is already registered successfully. Do I need the private variable in the header, which is for the OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener? It doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: @StefanM. I have checked your edit and will update my answer in 12 hours.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your great support! The good news: When clicking on a button and swiping to fragment2, I can see the correct text. The not so good news: When rotating the display (which re-creates the views), the value is not there anymore. I tried adding two bundle methods, but the app crashes now. I updated my first post with the current code.

Comment: @StefanM. Add these lines after you initialise `prefs` in `onCreateView` method. `String text = sharedPreferences.getString("text", "0"); textViewValue.setText(text);` and remove other code you added in my updated code, then try it.

Comment: Hello Aaditya, thank you very much. Yes, it worked! Additionally, I added another button and I updatd the first Page so that everything gets saved. After launching the app, background + text are still visible, also after rotating. A question: even though everything works, do you think it would be meaningful to work with methods/classes, in case I add more buttons? I mean classes/methods regarding the SharedPreferences. (I updated my first post with my newest codes.)

Comment: @StefanM I don't think that would be necessary. It will just work as intended as long as Key for your preference is same. (Also please select my post as answer if it actually worked)